# Add ManytoMany in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add a m2m relationship  with already created model objects like the following:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    client_shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0,blank=True, null=True)


class Group(models.Model):

    emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    groupmodels = models.ManyToManyField(GroupModels)
    sender_clients = models.ManyToManyField(Client)            #### this one
    receiver_clients = models.ManyToManyField(ReceiverClient)
    warehouses = models.ManyToManyField(Warehouse)
```

Here a `group` model can have multiple `sender_clients`.

In my serializers I have added the `Client` serializer as well like the following:

```
class GroupSenderClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ('user',)


class GroupsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    groupmodels = GroupModelsSerializer(many=True)
    sender_clients = GroupSenderClientSerializer(many=True)     ####this one 
    receiver_clients = ReceiverClientSerializer(many=True)
    warehouses = WarehouseSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = "__all__"


    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("v data", validated_data)
        items_objects = validated_data.pop('groupmodels', None)
        sc_objects = validated_data.pop('sender_clients', None)
        rc_objects = validated_data.pop('receiver_clients', None)
        ware_objects = validated_data.pop('warehouses', None)
        prdcts = []
        sc = []
        rc = []
        ware = []
        for item in items_objects:
            i = GroupModels.objects.create(**item)
            prdcts.append(i)
        instance = Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print("sc objects", sc_objects)

        if len(sc_objects)>0:
            for i in sc_objects:
                print("id", i['id'])
                inst = Client.objects.get(pk=i['id'])
                sc.append(inst)

        if len(rc_objects)>0:
            for i in rc_objects:
                inst = ReceiverClient.objects.get(pk=i['id'])
                rc.append(inst)

        if len(ware_objects)>0:
            for i in ware_objects:
                inst = Warehouse.objects.get(pk=i['id'])
                ware.append(inst)

        instance.groupmodels.set(prdcts)
        instance.sender_clients.set(sc)
        instance.receiver_clients.set(rc)
        instance.warehouses.set(ware)
        return instance
```

But when I am passing the data to it like the following:

```
{'name': '546', 'emp': 14, 'sender_clients': [{'pk': 3}, {'pk': 4}], 'receiver_clients': [], 'warehouses': [], 'groupmodels': []}
```

the validated data gets only the following data:

```
v data {'groupmodels': [], 'sender_clients': [OrderedDict(), OrderedDict()], 'receiver_clients': [], 'warehouses': [], 'name': '546', 'emp': <Employee: Employee object (14)>}
```

Why does the `sender_clients` gets converted to blank dictionaries ? Do I need to change my `GroupSenderClientSerializer` to something else ?

Comment: Seems like `sender_clients` payload did not pass deserialization process and returned an empty dict. Some thoughts - if you are only sending `pk`-s in `sender_clients`, why not to use [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) ?

Comment: @Ersain I tried that but the validated_data changes to  `{'groupmodels': [], 'receiver_clients': [], 'warehouses': [], 'name': '546', 'emp': <Employee: Employee object (14)>}`, it doesn't have `sender_clients` anymore